# Can't create text file or append to it in NGINX without CHMOD 777

Tags: php, nginx, file-put-contents

Using Lightsail NGINX instance and got a one line in a PHP file that won't do what I need

```
$s = 'Hello world';
$myfile = file_put_contents('log.txt', $s.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

I want it to create the log.txt file if it's not there. If it is there, I want it to append. It does not do either.

If I create the file, it doesn't work. Only if I chmod the file to 777 via SSH will it work.

However a future piece of work would be to make the file so for reasons beyond the security of 777, this manual approach won't be feasible.

I understand this is down to security settings but really unsure on what to do to make this as secure as I can whilst still giving the PHP access to create/append to a text file

It appears I have a user called www-data. I have tried:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data html
sudo chmod -R g+s html
```

Still can't create the file.

If I put error reporting on I get:

```
file_put_contents(log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Thanks

Comment: The destination folder needs to have permissions that allow the `www-data` user to write to it. As well, all folders above it need permissions that allow that user to traverse them.

Comment: And, if your system uses something like SELinux, it needs to allow the write to the folder as well.

Comment: Added to my question - I have set www-data as owner and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

I'm really wondering how people advise on doing `chmod` or `chown` while completely lacking details of OP's server setup.

Based on everything mentioned so far, I can *assume* that the OP has things running this way:

- NGINX running as `www-data`.
- PHP-FPM running as different username (thus the permission issue). Let's say the PHP-FPM pool's username is `foo`.

Let's outline the best practices for this kind of setup. Following that, you'll be good with no permissions issues, in no time.

### Who must own the files

Usually (multi-site server or not), you want one specific user who owns the site files. That user should *never* be `www-data`. It must be a separate user that you have created for this purpose: `foo`.

As a rule, that same user `foo` will be the one who is set to run PHP-FPM pool with.

So set the correct ownership to the `foo` user:

```
chown -R foo:foo /path/to/your/site/html
```

Since PHP-FPM scripts run as `foo`, now that the directory and all the files inside it are owned by that very same `foo`, the PHP-FPM can do its stuff there without any problem. In that way, you will absolutely never have even the possibility that PHP cannot create / access stuff.

### Grant access to web server

Remember, there are two users involved in the setup: one is web server's (`www-data`) and one is PHP-FPM's (`foo`).

Now that the files are properly owned by `foo`, we need to grant the rights to *read* them to `www-data`. Why only read? Because NGINX has nothing to do with writing to the filesystem in this setup. It only needs to read files and traverse directories.

How this granting is usually accomplished is by making web server's user *to be a member of the site user's group*. This is a bit hard to comprehend at first, but I'll be further verbose about it:

Let's say there is a site file `data.txt`, that is now owned by `foo:foo` - the ownership in Linux is double-fold: file is owned by `foo` user and `foo` group.

Right now the `foo` group has only one member: `foo` user.

What we need to do is to add another member to the `foo` group:  the `www-data` user.

Thus:

```
usermod -a -G foo www-data
```

After this, the `foo` group has these members: `foo` user, `www-data` user.

And now we can continue onto permissions :)

### What permissions should be

Now that we're done with ownership, the remaining important bit is to adjust permissions for all files and directories in this way:

- directories should allow for traversing (`+x`) for group
- files should allow being read (`+r`) for group

These permissions are required for `www-data` to be able to read every website file and directory.

Most likely, you don't need to explicitly set those, because `umask` setting (I will not touch upon this topic here), will be already such that all files already have these permissions.

But if you need to fix your stuff, you can do:

```
chmod -R g+rX /path/to/your/site/html
```

The uppercase `X` ensures that `+x` is set for directories only.

### Going secure

After setting up the right file and group ownership for this kind of setup, you can go further secure and set more restrictive `chmod`.

For example, [Magento secure chmod](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/magento-chmod-1)  follows that setup's conventions so you can be fine with `chmod` permissions of `0400` for PHP files and `0640` for media files :)

The last `chmod` bit should *always* be 0 unless you're dealing with a truly odd use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that better way to achieve your goal, is chown command. This changes ownership of file.

Try run

```
chown username yourfile
```

You can also use this for folder

```
chown -R username yourfolder
```

In your case, you probably need change ownership of file log.txt

Comment: I did this on log.php (the PHP file) but it still will not create text files

Comment: Maybe you need to do this on txt file, that you try to make/override

Comment: How can I do it if it won't create it?

Comment: So change ownership of folder, where you want create this file :)  chown -R username yourfolder

Comment: I did and it still will not work: sudo chown -R www-data html

Comment: Try with sudo ?

Comment: See my comment - it is with sudo. Permission is now: drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data daemon 4.0K Apr 13 17:54 html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191792/discussion-between-kamil-naja-and-pee2pee).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ownership to nginx user.

`chown nginx: log.txt`